# How to use buttons to allow user to add/subtract input elements and maintain element value sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use "+" and "-" buttons to allow the user to add or subtract the number of possible choices for each question in a multiple choice quiz creation app.

The max number of choices per question is 4, and the minimum is 2.

The issue I am coming up against is that after adding a choice, the subtract button cannot read the value of the last radio button.

Also, the values of the radio buttons are there because they are used in other parts of the application, not just for this functionality. Therefore it is important that the radio button choices are consecutive, starting with 0.

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Here is a Codepen, but the code I am using is also below: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zKdzZv?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div id="q-container">
                <div class="qelem">
                    <h4>Question 1.)</h4>
                    <input type="text" class="question" style="width:400px"
                           placeholder=" Who was the 2nd president of the United States?">
                    <br>

                    <br>
                    <ul style="list-style:none;" class="choices">
                        <li><input type="radio" name="rad" value="0"><input type="text" class="choice" placeholder=" John Hancock"></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="rad" value="1"><input type="text" class="choice" placeholder=" Adam Smith"></li>
                        <li><input type="radio" name="rad" value="2"><input type="text" class="choice" placeholder=" John Adams"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs choiceAmt" role="group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="add"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></small></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn" id="sub"><small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></small></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
        var num;
        var lastRadioVal = $(this).parents(".qelem").find("input:radio").last().val();
        console.log("lastRadioVal = " +lastRadioVal);
        num = lastRadioVal+1;
        $(this).parents(".qelem").children(".choices").append(
            '<li><input type="radio" name="rad" value="'+num+'">
                 <input type="text" class="choice"></li>'
        );
        if(lastRadioVal = 3){
            $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        }
        if(lastRadioVal > 1){
            $("#sub").prop('disabled',false);
        }
        console.log("lastRadioVal = " +lastRadioVal);
    });

    $("#sub").click(function(){
        var lastRadioVal = $(this).parents(".qelem").find("input:radio").last().val();
        console.log("lastRadioVal = " +lastRadioVal);
        $(this).parents(".qelem").find("li").last().remove();
        lastRadioVal--;
        if(lastRadioVal = 1){
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
        $("#add").prop('disabled', false);
        console.log("lastRadioVal = " +lastRadioVal);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of finding the last val of the radio elements, I called `.length` on children of the `.choices` ul, stored that in a variable on each button click, and used if statements, and it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Why call a convoluted (and low performance) scanning selector like this? Perhaps you have a reason?

If it was me I would just add IDs to the buttons and simply call them directly.
$('#radioid').value();

something along those lines. Does that help? Finding parents/children and scanning down the dom till you find something should IMHO be avoided at all costs. Sometimes it's useful but really it creates a maintence nightmare when in a year pages get refactored and someone not aware of your dom scanning code changes the HTML and then your code starts running against their HTML and the fun of jquery truly begins.

does that help at all?

Using IDs will save your life in jQuery.